# How can I record a video of my screen, without any noticeable compression?

Tags: ms-office, video, quicktime, encoding, screensaver

So I have a client who wanted us to design them a screensaver... In PowerPoint... *"The client's always right!"*

I have created it and need to record the animated output into a .mov file, for import into a screensaver creator program. My dilemma is this...

1. When choosing to *Export as Movie* from Powerpoint, it exports without animation - which isn't very helpful
2. When using QuickTime Player to record the screen, it records it - but has noticeable compression artefacts throughout the animation

I'm fine to purchase a copy of something like ScreenFlow, but I'm wondering if anyone can point me to any alternative/better solutions, before I cough up £70 on Screenflow... The Powerpoint is only 30 seconds long, so I'm not fussed about file size without any compression.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Screenium](http://www.syniumsoftware.com/screenium/) if it suits your needs, I have used it for a few projects and it worked great.